# Why is xts implemented as a matrix rather than a data frame?

Tags: r, xts

I've found some information about xts fields representation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470735/r-converting-data-frame-mixed-factor-and-numeric-to-xts-in-r) thread but I'm still not clear why xts is an index + a matrix. Why not an index + a data frame?  Wouldn't that allow more flexibility when working with factors and numeric columns?

Once I've loaded data in xts most of the work consists in performing numerical operations on a full set or a subset of the time series. For this the indexing works very well, but I am forced to go through calls like `data.frame(data.matrix(myxts))` to be able to extract factors and numerical columns.

In addition I find more convenient to use the $ notation than the matrix indexing, although this is really a different question. For example:

```
lm(myxts$Res ~ myxts$ThisVar + myxts$ThatVar)
```

is easier to write than

```
lm(myxts[, "Res"] ~ myxts[, "ThisVar"] + myxts[, "ThatVar"]).
```

Comment: I really wish it used data.frames, as most data in health data science is more complex than a simple numerical matrix and includes factors...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

xts uses matrix rather than data.frame because:

1. it is a subclass of zoo, and that's how zoo objects are structured, and
2. matrix objects have much better performance than data.frames.

Your second question could be solved by using the `data=` argument to `lm` or, more generally, by using `with`:

```
with(myxts, lm(Res ~ ThisVar + ThatVar))
```

Comment: This answer my question, but how costly is the data.matrix() call to work on numbers? Doesn't it defeat the purpose of using a character matrix vs. data frame in xts for better perfomances?

Comment: I'm scratching my head. There are never factor variables in a matrix (of any sort) because matrix objects remove all attributes except names and dimensions. I believe you are missing the point Joshua is making: that you do not need to wrap EITHER `data.frame` OR `data.matrix` around the xts-object to get its numeric values into `lm` when it is accessed using `with` or passed as a data argument to `lm`.

Comment: Also `zoo` is designed as an enhanced `ts` class (in the core of R) which in turn is based on matrices.  See the zoo Design vignette: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-design.pdf .  Note that zoo does support `$`. e.g. `library(zoo); z <- zoo(cbind(a = 1:3, b = 4:6)); z$a` .  By the way, the performance difference is quite significant between matrices and data frames.

Comment: @RobertKubrick: I'm not sure.  We have not spent a lot of time optimizing xts for time-series estimation.  The performance I refer to can be seen in the ability to manipulate xts objects with tens or hundreds of millions of elements very quickly.

Comment: @DWin matrix do not have factors but I do need them. That is why I convert back to a data frame.

Comment: I'm still a bit puzzled about these character to numeric implicit conversions. I know atoi() is relatively expensive. Unless R stores both representations internally (like Perl, if I'm not mistaken) then the slowdown might be substantial. Aren't we all running numerical analysis on the time series?

Comment: Then why not `lm(Res ~ ThisVar+ factor(ThatVar), data=myxts)`?

Comment: @DWin Yes, that answer my second question. There is still an implicit numerical conversion going through ThisVar though?

Comment: Robert, the cost is not the conversion, the cost is the *access* of elements. Matrices strongly outperform data.frames, and that has been throroughly debated on r-devel over the years.